# many-to-many relation on Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a class "Team", which can have many Users.

I need to create a from/to relation every time a user is added to a Team. Every user can rate and be rated by all his teammates.

This is my Cloud code. I can't seem to get this working.

```
// add Team relations for every saved player
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Team", function(request) {

    // Team being saved
    var team = request.object,
        relation = team.relation("players"),
        query = relation.query();

        query.find({

            // players on this Team
            success: function(results) {

                // all players on this Team
                var i, j, player, teammate;
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    player = results[i];

                    // for each player add a new Rate relation (from/to)
                    for (j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                        teammate = results[i];

                        // if it's same player, escape relation
                        if (player == teammate) { continue; }

                        var Rate = Parse.Object.extend("Rate"),
                            rate = new Rate();

                        // create the relation from this player
                        var fromRelation = rate.relation('from');
                            fromRelation.add(player);

                        // to every other player on the team
                        var toRelation = rate.relation('to');
                            toRelation.add(teammate);

                            rate.save(null, {
                                success: function(_team) {

                                },
                                error: function(_team, error) {

                                }
                            });
                    }
                }

                response.success('rate relation success');

            },
            error: function(error) {
                response.error('rate relation error');
            }
        });

});
```

Adding a player to a team is working great, it runs on Client side.

Classes setup on Data Browser:
[image: Team Class]
[image: Rate Class]

Answer (score 1):

Your class is "Rates" but you are using this code:

```
 var Rate = Parse.Object.extend("Rate"),
                        rate = new Rate();
```

change to

```
 var Rate = Parse.Object.extend("Rates"),
                        rate = new Rate();
```

Also, make sure your object is created before adding a relation.

```
                        var Rate = Parse.Object.extend("Rate"),
                        rate = new Rate();

                           [.... MOVED BELOW .....}

                        rate.save(null, {
                            success: function(_team) {
                           [.... now create and save relations ...]
                            },
```

Comment: thanks for catching that, still no success though, no new rows are created

Comment: can you log the errors for us and let me know what they are?

Comment: try saving the Rate, so an objectID is created and THEN add the relation and save. I had a lot of problems getting my many to many relations to work too. Also, make sure you have actual parse objects. See edited answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way.

The only thing annoying me is the fact that if I try this, I get an error:

"fromRelation is expecting _User, but got _Team", why?

```
player = results[i];
var fromRelation = rate.relation('from');
fromRelation.add(player);
```

I had to create 2 new vars, fromPlayer and toPlayer, although it seems dumb to me, anyway it works.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateTeamPlayers", function(request, response) {
    var Team = Parse.Object.extend("Team"),
        team = new Team();
        team.id = request.params.id;

    var relation = team.relation("players"),
        query = relation.query();

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            var i, j, player, teammate, queryArray = [], teammateRes = results;

            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                player = results[i];

                // for each player add a new Rate relation (from/to)
                for (j = 0; j < teammateRes.length; j++) {
                    teammate = teammateRes[j];

                    // if it's same player, escape relation
                    if (player == teammate) { continue; }

                    var Rate = Parse.Object.extend("Rates"),
                        rate = new Rate();

                    // create the relation from this player
                    var fromPlayer = new Parse.User();
                        fromPlayer.id = player.id;

                    var fromRelation = rate.relation('from');
                        fromRelation.add(fromPlayer);

                    // to every other player on the team
                    var toPlayer = new Parse.User();
                        toPlayer.id = teammate.id;

                    var toRelation = rate.relation('to');
                        toRelation.add(toPlayer);

                    queryArray.push(rate);
                }
            }

            Parse.Object.saveAll(queryArray, {
                success: function(_allsaved) {
                    response.success('rate save success:' + _allsaved);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    response.error('rate save error:' + error + ' =|= ' + error.message);
                }
            });

            // end suucess
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("team failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Chris, the reason it is working now is because you now have created and obtained the objects which you are building the relationships with. Before, you were attempting to make a relation with objects that 'didn't exist'.